# Rickshaw Log scale graphs and slider scaling

Tags: d3.js, rickshaw

I've been trying to understand how the sliders in Rickshaw/D3 interact with the scaling of a graph. It seems that when I use both together for a dynamic graph which displays a subset of the data selected by the slider, the log scale is not correct. Is there something I'm not doing right?  Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a5r29/6/) and a subset of the code is here.

The HTML used to initialise the graphs:

```
<div id="time">
    <div id="yearindicator"></div>
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
<div id="charts" class="clearfix">
    <div class="chart">
         <h3>Total</h3>

        <div id="y_axis"></div>
        <div id="chart_one"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And a subset of the javascript is

```
logScale = d3.scale.log().domain([1, 1000]).range([0, 1]);
var data = [ {.... data not shown }];

var graph_one = new Rickshaw.Graph({
    element: document.querySelector("#chart_one"),
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    renderer: 'scatterplot',
    series: data

});

new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X({
    graph: graph_one
});

new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled({
    graph: graph_one,
    orientation: 'left',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
    scale: logScale
});

graph_one.render();


var slider_one = new Rickshaw.Graph.RangeSlider({
    element: document.querySelector('#slider-range'),
    graph: graph_one
});

var y_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y.Scaled({
    graph: graph_1,
    orientation: 'left',
    tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
    element: document.getElementById('y_axis'),
    scale: logScale
});
```

Comment: Which one is the _log scale_ in your case? In your jsfiddle, both axis look fine to me - they both adjust when using the slider.